# Convert string automatically to inline image

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign's data merge to generate playing cards for my game. Is it possible to convert a specific string to an inline image?

```
"You may roll :red_die: and add the rolled valued to this card's value"
```

For example the *:red_die:* in the text above would be automatically converted to an inline icon of a red coloured die.

Comment: No programming solution asked nor (specifically) required - this question may have been more appropriate at [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: Thanks for the information, Jongware. I'll be sure to position the question to the right place next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't this way. But you can place images with datamerge to the condition some fields of your source is set as an image one meaning having a "@" prefix. InDesign will process fields like @image as an image to place. It's up to you to add such a field in your source. However you can't nest it within another datamerge tag so it may not work eventually.
Other solution is using F/C dialog to replace :red_die: with clipboard content (your image) or to use scripting. You may also consider variable content plugin like EasyCatalog.

Comment: To save others grom googling, you can just write ^c to the replace box. This way InDesign will use the contents of your clipboard to replace the matching words. I created a dummy text field with the inline image off the canvas. This way I can easily copy it there to be replaced in the text fields.